# Injection of dependencies in a filter function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm writing a custom filter which depends on a constant object named `config`. This is what I've got so far:

```
angular.module('myproject.filters', []).filter('userLink', function () {
    return function (user) {
        return '';
    };
});
```

I need to inject the '`config`' module into my filter so I can pull a static value out of it for building the link to a given user object.

How do I inject dependencies into filter functions?

Comment: You should probably use a service for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inject a service or a constant as a dependency like this

```
angular.module('myproject.filters', [])
    .filter('userLink', ['config', function (config) {
        return function (user) {
            if (user == null)
                return "#";

            return config.appRoot + '/user/' + user.id + "/";
        };
    }]);
```

If this depends on a `config` module like you mention, be sure to include that in your module statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject dependencies into filters the same way you inject into controllers, services and factories.

```
angular.module('myproject.filters', ['config'])
.filter('userLink', ['$compile', '$timeout', 'configService', function ($compile, $timeout, configService) {
    return function (user) {
        return '';
    };
}]);
```

As eddiec pointed out if `config` is a module you must include it as a dependency for your `myproject.filters`. Then to include a service within the `config` module in the filter you inject it within the filter method.